# Is there an excel formula like INDIRECT to get a dependent drop down from another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

[image: Workbook1]

[image: Workbook2]

How can I get dependent dropdown in cell `D2` based on dropdown value chosen in cell `C2` in Workbook1 from Workbook2? The `INDIRECT` method seems to work for different sheets in the same workbook. Couldn't find a method that worked for different workbooks.

Example -

> C2 value - Services, D2 should load - Third party service, and so on
>
> C2 value - Medical Devices, D2 should load - Dosimetry and so on.

These values are in Workbook2. I successfully loaded values in C2 but can't load dependent values in D2. How can I load the dependent values?

Comment: You need to link data to another workbook?  That doesn't require `INDIRECT`.

Comment: Yes I do. I need to load values in D2 based on dropdown value selected in C2. If value in C2 changes, D2 should be updated with new values.

Comment: It seems to me you are trying to describe a `VLOOKUP` formula here.

Comment: To refer to a value in a cell in a different workbook use =[Workbook name]Sheet name!cell ref. IF the names have spaces you will need to wrap single quotes around it. So to refer to cell C3 in sheet1 in workbook1 you would write =[Workbook1]sheet1!C3

Comment: @PriyankaDembla See my answer.  Both DropDowns update when either is changed

Comment: @Rawrplus - Vlookup is not what I am looking for. The column index is not the same for every range. Thank you for replying though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you feel that you need `INDIRECT` but I just got an example working without it.

(`INDIRECT` should generally be avoided for a number of reasons.)

---

> ### `test.xlsm` :
>
> `A1:A5` populated with `A,B,C,D,E`
>
> **Drop Down 1:**
>   <kbd>Input Range:</kbd>  `$A$1:$A$5`
>    <kbd>Cell Link:</kbd>   `[Book2]Sheet1!$A$1`
>   [image: img]

---

> ### `book2.xlsm` :
>
> `A1` = cell link
>
> **Drop Down 1:**
>   <kbd>Input Range:</kbd>  `[test.xlsm]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5`
>    <kbd>Cell Link:</kbd>   `$A$1`
>   [image: img]

---

[image: scr]

Comment: Would you be kind enough to post a better image of test.xlsm?

Comment: @PriyankaDembla - updated.  Is this the functionality that you intended?  (I'm curious *why* you would want this to happen.)

Comment: Why should we avoid `INDIRECT`?

Comment: I have updated my question. Please look at the images and the updated example.

Comment: @Jeepad - The colors are not decided by me. It's what the client has given us. :) Also, Please don't type everything. You can just ignore the question. Thank you.

Comment: @ashleedawg - Thank you for your effort. I understand how it can be done.